# Codename one "Could not find or load main class #" message

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to build my first codename one app with Intellij however each time I try to run the app using the plugin default's run config "Run in device Simulator" the following message is displayed

"Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:38947', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:38947', transport: 'socket'
Error: Could not find or load main class #"

I have tried using brand new project with no code and downloaded a demo with the same result. Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: I have just tested and it is working and it is working in Eclipse which is not ideal for me. Is there anything wrong with the plugin?

Comment: This should work fine in intellij. Which version of Java are you using as your JDK? Make sure you're using Oracle JDK 8 (not newer, older or open JDK) or alternatively Open JDK 11.

Comment: Thanks, I have reinstalled Intellij and it is working now.